# How to initialize a config file without overwriting mountPath

Tags: kubernetes

I need to place a config file default.json in a container mountPath that already have other config files. The way I tried to do this, seems to overwrite the path causing the system not to see the other files in the same directory.

Any ideas how I can do this?

The below code hide the other files from the system.

```
initContainers:
        - name: install
          image: busybox
          command:
          - wget
          - "-O"
          - "/usr/share/nginx/html/config/default.json"
          - https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/.../default.json
          volumeMounts:
            - name: console-config
              mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html/config"      
      volumes:
        - name: console-config
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using subPath field, you can mount the directory or file without overwriting other files, you can find  more information here [subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

```
   initContainers:
        - name: install
          image: busybox
          command:
          - wget
          - "-O"
          - "/usr/share/nginx/html/config/default.json"
          - https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/.../default.json
          volumeMounts:
            - name: console-config
              mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html/config"
              subPath: config                      
      volumes:
        - name: console-config
          emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh, but if I do this there is nothing in the config directory . Any other suggestions, something I am missing? Is that emptyDir type not a problem.

Comment: Hi Anton, If the config file has the content already then you should mount it using ConfigMap, and use subpath.

Comment: Emptydir has different purpose , Here is the arictle which explain https://medium.com/uptime-99/kubernetes-emptydir-is-not-the-same-as-dockers-volumes-from-3f561e64648c

Comment: Thanks again Suresh, if I use a configMap without the subPath I can see the single file in the container but if I add the subPath: config there are no files. kubectl create configmap console-config --from-file=default.json

Comment: Can we try  do ``` mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html/config/default.json"
              subPath: dedault.json```

Comment: Here is another example https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/multiple-kubernetes-volumes-directory

Comment: GENIUS!!! Thanks Suresh, using mountPath and subPath with the file specified worked. Really appreciate your help!